# What is the benefit of going for administrative review for Tier 5 UK refusal if additional grounds are unjustified?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, working-visas

I applied for Tier 5 visa (Temporary Worker Government Authorized Exchange). I got a refusal under rule 245ZO (Maintenance) but, surprisingly in the last paragraph, two rules of not attending an interview & not providing tuberculosis certificate were added although they are not needed in my case in principle.

Will it be beneficial to go for administrative review, at least to eliminate those 2 unjustified rules? In principle, is it better to be refused under one rule (245ZO) than being refused on 3 rules (two of them are general grounds of refusal)?

If administrative review was unsuccessful, would that be considered another refusal in my immigration history?

[image][image]

Comment: This is a question for our sister site [expatriates.se].

Comment: Your 'additional grounds' are unlikely to succeed: whatever it was happened during your interview: *320: (7D) failure, without providing a reasonable explanation, to comply with a request made on behalf of the Entry Clearance Officer to attend for interview. (8A) where the person seeking leave is outside the United Kingdom, failure by him to supply any information, documents, copy documents or medical report requested by an Immigration Officer.* The ECO notes will document what was asked and what you did not provide, and it is probably useless to argue those points.

Comment: The tuberculosis section is marked n/a which means "not applicable" so you don't need to worry about that part.

Comment: Dear Georgio. There is no interview for Tier 5 visa in principle. By assumption, it was needed later. I do confirm that it was only a peroid of 7 days between receiving documents by Ukvi & the decision. I have not received any requests during this time.

Comment: Dear mkennedy, thank you for your comment. Yes, i noted. I was wondering why did ECO include the rule of tuberculosis in the last paragraph?

Comment: I rolled back the edit. It is important to include the refusal letter, since it shows that the question is based on a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have misunderstood. The refusal says

> I have refused your visa application... because I am not satisfied that you meet all of the requirements of paragraphs 245ZO, 3207D and 320 8A of the Immigration Rules.

That doesn't say that you failed all three tests. It just says that you didn't pass them all (you passed two out of three), so you didn't get the visa.

Comment: Dear David, i do not find that this satisfactory at all. ECO would normally mention the rules of “ concern”. Would it be easier to say “I am not satisfied you meet requirements of paragraph 245ZO”?!!!’ Why to mention 3 & then say not meet “ all”. I think there may be more convenient explanation.

Comment: @AmrSaqr It's a form letter. The ECO doesn't sit down and type a brand new letter from scratch. Probably every refusal latter ends with that paragraph.

Comment: Dear David. Thank you for interest. But, No, it doesn’t. Not every refusal letter ends with that paragraph.

Comment: OK, fine. But, honestly, what are you trying to achieve here? The refusal does _not_ say that you failed to attend an interview or that you failed to present TB documentation. The final paragraph is exactly correct: you did not, in the opinion of the ECO, meet _all three_ criteria. The paragraph does not claim that you failed all three; just that you didn't meet them all. There is no problem here.

Comment: I am trying to figure out should i go for administrative review, would this overturned or not. Your comments are appreciated.

Comment: Hey @AmrSaqr, administrative review is meant for cases where the caseworker made a material error in their processing of your case, and which if corrected, would change the outcome. Examples include a) the maintenance documents provided are indeed under your name and they misread, or b) your sponsor has a statement attached that states you will not claim public fund and they skipped right through. Non-examples include the caseworker being sloppy and use the template for Tier 4 when you are applying for Tier 5 visa, or a confusing yet factually correct refusal conclusion.

Comment: @AmrSaqr Furthermore, they did specifically mentioned which rule you are refused on - (maintenance box, last line) "I therefore refuse your application under paragraph 245ZO(c) of the Immigration Rules." Again, while their letter construction is indeed sloppy, and give grounds for you to _complain_, it is unlikely an administrative review will change the outcome (to get you an visa), _if the **material fact** they stated in the maintenance box is true_. It is better to address that as your priority (as money transfer takes time).

Comment: @B.Liu, Dear B.Liu, your is clarification is very satisfactory. You now get me a new idea that i had not thinked about before. It is a matter of “ Sloppy Structure”. I do greet you also for picking up the fault of “ Tier 4 general student” visa in the maintenance. Please accept my appreciation, you read each line carefully. I am convinced with your view. Multiple errors indicate poor structure rather than specific meanings. Currently, i have you options. I already deposited the money to save effort convincing my sponsor to certify maintenance on my behalf.

Comment: @B.Liu, the outstsnding two questions..1) will i need a new CoS ? 2) Is better to wait my account be mature & apply for fresh Tier 5 PBS application or to go for visitor visa “ academic”? . I will fully funded by organzation to do my research by the sponsor “ UCL”.

Comment: @AmrSaqr Unfortunately they are out of my domain knowledge, so it is an _educated guess_ below (i.e. don't count on me) - the best idea is to contact UCL for next steps as surely they will have someone that handles such queries. 1) Extremely likely. 2) The best (and fastest) way is perhaps to negotiate with UCL and get them to state that you are not going to claim public funds in a new CoS. Failing that, visitor visa is more risky as you need a new set of documents (which include that you have the fund to sustain yourself, required for Tier 5 anyway), and you are on your own (no UCL support).

Comment: @B.Liu, yes I receive no support from university regarding “ maintenance certification “ which is a sole authority of your employment sponsor. But - in fact - i have another sponsor for funds- prestigious organization- ( scholarship) which will provide me of all funds needed during my stay peroid in the UK. Consequently, i will go for visitor visa with their financial supporting documents. Do you have expectations regarding this issue? Regards,

Comment: @AmrSaqr Sadly I can't comment further due to my lack of knowledge on visitor visas. You really need to speak to UCL / your scholarship provider for their input, and all I can do is to wish you the very best of luck to navigate this through. Sorry.